# Make image same size using also bootstrap grid system

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, ejs

how can i make the images received from my database at the same height using also the bootstrap grid system so i can put for example on 1 row 2 img portrait and 1 landscape?

index.html

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row d-flex">
    <% let portrait = 'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12';
    let landscape = 'col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12';%>
    <% gallery.forEach(function (image) { %>

    <% if (image.format === 'portrait') { %>
    <div class="<%= portrait%>" style="padding: 5px">
        <a class="" href="/gallery/#<%= image.imageName %>">
            <img src="<%= image.path + image.imageName %>" alt="<%= image.imageName %>" class="img-responsive"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <% } else if (image.format === 'landscape') { %>
   <div class="<%=landscape%>" style="padding: 5px">
       <a class="" href="/gallery/#<%= image.imageName %>">
           <img src="<%= image.path + image.imageName %>" alt="<%= image.imageName %>" class="img-responsive"/>
       </a>
   </div>
    <% } %>
```

style.css

```
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

.d-flex > [class ^= "col-lg"] {
    display: flex;
}

img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

output:
[image]

i need to make the landscape picture at the same height as the portrait

Comment: In bootstrap 4 version class `.img-responsive` has been renamed to `.img-fluid.` read more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#images)

Comment: in this old project i used bootstrap 3 @JyotiPathania

Comment: Pretty raunchy pics lol

Answer (score 0):

You can also use img{ height:100%; max-height:100%; width:auto;}
It will set height of all images equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Check Demo **[HERE](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/QQwqWK?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516703914899-e8303d01329a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=9ebf86cdab3a1c7319ff15b16d09b1f7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472653525502-fc569e405a74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=3c19e4553dd56ab02a6674ef2c649474&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1423483641154-5411ec9c0ddf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=0649227cc8b0717bed784c53c7fdc070&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
.d-flex > [class ^= "col-sm"] {
  display: flex;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: i've reedited the post with some of your code and that's my output in the picture

Comment: @Adrian since you have wrapped `<img>` with `<a>` tag. Just give the `d-flex` class to `<a>` tag also. I hope it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Tanks @Jyoti Pathania for the implication i managed to achive what i have desired starting from your ideea ; Here is a fiffle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uso7wrnm/). Know it looks ok

Comment: @Adrian Your Welcome.. :)